# How to click on a hyperlink in Selenium using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, hyperlink, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting on Selenium. I am trying to invoke click actions upon links on a web page, but for some reason, selenium.click() event is not even showing on the intellisense! inside the foreach loop. Below is partial code of what I am trying to do.

```
    IWebDriver driver;
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    List<IWebElement> links = new List<IWebElement>();
    links= driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).ToList();
    //driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("YouTube")).Click();
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        OpenQA.Selenium....;
        ..
    }
```

Please note that the click works fine in the commented line above the foreach loop.
Am I missing a reference?

Answer (score 7):

Why do you expect `selenium.Click();` to show up? From the code you provided, looks like you are using WebDriver, not Selenium RC or WebDriverBackSelenium. You probably should consider using something like `link.Click();`.

Here is what I do using WebDriver, which works fine for me.

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

// find directly, note it's not in the <a> but in <span>
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='YouTube']")).Click();

// your logic with LINQ
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
links.First(element => element.Text == "YouTube").Click();

// your logic with traditional foreach loop
foreach (var link in links) {
    if (link.Text == "YouTube") {
        link.Click();
        break;
    }
}

driver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `By` method is not finding your TagName. Try the `By.LinkText("a")` instead:

```
links= driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("a")).ToList();
```

Or try other `By` methods (id,className,...)

€:

```
List<IWebElement> links = new List<IWebElement>();
    links.add(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")));
    //driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("YouTube")).Click();

links.get(0).click();
```

Comment: Actually, it does. The problem I am facing is that within the loop, selenium.click(...) should be available as I saw in many examples. However, it is not there. Selenium does not list click() as an available method that I can use. The ...ToList() actually fills the links list with all the available links on the page and they are all correct.

Comment: maybe you got something wrong in your code. I'm java programmer, from my point of view you define links as a method? I would possibly write it like in my above edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try casting he link to IWebELement in your foreach loop like:

```
 foreach(IWebELelent link in links) 
{
------
-----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("")).SendKeys(Open.QA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

Either way is possible